# Access openSearch:totalResults using feedparser

Tags: feedparser

How can I retrieve the openSearch:totalResults attribute using feedparser?

I have a blogger API result which looks  a bit like this (I have cut out some stuff to make it compact here)

```
 <feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
  xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'
  xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
  gd:etag='W/"CUYMQ348fyp7ImA9WB9UFkU."'>
 <id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-blogID.postpostID..comments</id>
 <updated>2007-12-14T17:46:22.077-08:00</updated>
 <title>Comments on Lizzy's Diary: Quite disagreeable</title>  
 <generator version='7.00'
   uri='http://www.blogger.com'>Blogger</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>1</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
```

Currently, I do something like

```
req = urllib.urlopen(url)
urlContent = req.read()            
feed = feedparser.parse(urlContent)
print feed.feed['openSearch_totalResults']
```

I get an error with the above code that the attribute does not exist. I have confirmed that the feed parser has the namespace by running

```
print feed['namespaces']
```

which gives me

```
{'': u'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', u'gd': u'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005', u'thr': u'http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0', u'openSearch': u'http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/'}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the capitalization: it should be `opensearch_totalresults` instead of `openSearch_totalResults`. Thus, the correct line would be:

```
print feed.feed['opensearch_totalresults']
```